# Getting "NotImplementedError" in a Python program

Tags: pycharm

Error:

```
C:\Users\wande\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\wande\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py 
Unhandled exception in listener callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wande\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\win32.py", line 386, in _handler
    converted = self._convert(code, msg, lpdata)
  File "C:\Users\wande\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\win32.py", line 401, in _convert
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wande\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 228, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wande\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\win32.py", line 390, in _handler
    self._handle(code, msg, lpdata)
  File "C:\Users\wande\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pynput\mouse\_win32.py", line 212, in _handle
    self.on_click(data.pt.x, data.pt.y, button, pressed)
  File "C:\Users\wande\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 144, in inner
    if f(*args) is False:
  File "C:\Users\wande\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 39, in on_click
    minhaPrint.save(os.path.join(diretorioRaiz, + "printkeylogger_" + horarioPrint + ".jpg"))
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

Code:

```
def on_click(x, y, buttom, pressed): if pressed: minhaPrint = py.screenshot() hora = datetime.now() horarioPrint = hora.strftime,("%H:%M:%S,") minhaPrint.save(os.path.join(diretorioRaiz, + "printkeylogger_" + horarioPrint + ".jpg"))
```

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and add the relevant code to the question. Also what is up with the title of your question?

Comment: Please add the code to the question again - it has melded the code into one line, which will break Python code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is a TypeError. This means that Python is trying to perform an operation on a type of data that is not supported. In this case, the error is occurring because you are trying to concatenate a string with a unary operator.

The line of code that is causing the error is:

```
minhaPrint.save(os.path.join(diretorioRaiz, + "printkeylogger" + horarioPrint + ".jpg"))
```

The `+` symbol in this line is a unary operator. It is used to negate a value. However, strings cannot be negated. Therefore, Python is giving you an error.

To fix this error, you need to remove the `+` symbol from the line of code. This will allow Python to correctly concatenate the string with the path to the file.

The corrected line of code would be:

```
minhaPrint.save(os.path.join(diretorioRaiz, "printkeylogger" + horarioPrint + ".jpg"))
```

Once you have made this change, the code should run without any errors.

Comment: An excellent answer to a dreadfully unclear question! (Per the edit though, please learn how to use Markdown in the editor).